# Retrieve value of private key after encryption with the public key

Tags: rsa, public-key

Is there a way to find an RSA private key after it is encrypted with the corresponding public key? Does there exist an algorithm to recover the private key in this special case?

Comment: This is called circular security. I believe that the answer is not completely understood in the research community.

Answer (score 3):

If an appropriate padding mechanism is used then you *cannot* directly encrypt the private key with the public key as the input size would be too large. If hybrid encryption is used (RSA + AES) then the answer is *no*.

You could possibly raise (modulo $n$) the *private exponent* to the power of the public exponent. So then you would need to retrieve $d$ from $d ^ e \mod n$. I don't see how you could retrieve $d$ from that, even if you take into account how $d$ and $n$ are calculated.

Note that you could not do this if you would require the CRT parameters instead of the private exponent $d$.

Comment: Obviously raising the modulus to the public key exponent modulo the same modulus does make zero (sense) :P